# Передача значения в JS

Tags: php, javascript, yii

Передаю значения в JS

```php
<div class="spoiler-title closed"> <?php echo $cls = Yii::t('graduates', '0424'), '&#9660'; ?> </div>

<div class="spoiler-body">
    <form name=form_recall>
        <input type=hidden id="id1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($opn = Yii::t('graduates', '0423')); ?>">
        <input type=hidden id="id2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($cls); ?>">
    </form>
    <img src="<?php echo StaticFilesHelper::createPath('image', 'graduates', "recall.png"); ?>">
</div>
```

код JS

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.spoiler-body').hide();
    $('.spoiler-title').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('opened').toggleClass('closed').next().slideToggle();
        if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
            var a = document.getElementById('id1').value;
            $(this).html(a + "\u25B2");
            //alert(tmp);
        }
        else {
            var b = document.getElementById('id2').value;
            $(this).html(b + "\u25BC");
        }
    });
});
```

Проблема в том что при использование js повторно (передавая другие значения) все остается без изменения.

Comment: <div class="spoiler-title closed"> <?php echo $cls = Yii::t('graduates', '0424'), '&#9660'; ?> </div>

Сейчас попробую $('#id1').val()

Comment: 1. `<div class="spoiler-title closed">` нужно добавить в вопрос. 2. Лучше в вопросе разместить "готовый" (показываемый в браузере) HTML код, в котором уже нет ни строчки PHP, так как вопрос, судя по описанию, связан только с HTML и JS. 3. Про `$('#id1').val()` вопрос к тому, что зачем писать более длинную конструкцию при использовании jQuery?

Comment: div добавил , за совет по поводу длинной строчки спасибо.

Comment: Второй пункт про HTML остаётся в силе. Плюс до сих пор непонятно что такое _повторное использование JS_  в данном случае.

Comment: создаю другом месте аналогичный <div> но хочу передать совсем другие значения, а проблема остается в том что остаются значения предыдущего

Comment: Задать другие значения в `<input>`'ах во второй форме?

Comment: да, именно в этом проблем. Я их задаю но на странице остаются предыдущие значения...

Comment: Я всё же (в третий раз) настоятельно рекомендую поместить в вопрос итоговый HTML (обеих форм), а не смесь PHP и HTML. По поводу `<input>`'ов во второй форме - а у них, случаем, не такие ID, как у `<input>`'ов в первой форме?

Comment: такие же. Но при смене id их соответсвено нужно менять и в js.
я думал id будут перезаписаны.

Comment: В JS коде указаны ID `id1` и `id2`. Если в HTML есть 2 элемента с ID `id1`, то выбираться будет только первый.

Comment: а можно как-то  повторно передать другие значения в js id1 и id2

Comment: Фраза _повторно передать другие значения_ как была мутной, так и осталась. У элемента с ID `id1` есть значение (`value`). Это значение в JS можно прочитать, можно изменить. Всего два действия со значением конкретного поля - чтение и запись. _Повторной передачи_ среди этих двух действий нет.